# How can I quickly grab just the git reflog from the last day?

Tags: git

I know that there is some kind of format that looks like `master@{"1 day ago"}` but I can't figure out how to use something to (in a friendly way) filter the output of `git reflog` to just the last X amount of time.

I tried `git reflog --since="2 days ago"` but it is definitely not giving me the results that I expect (as it produces 3 results all related to the current branch I'm on, and the first 36 entries in `git reflog` are from today).

Mainly I just need a list of all the (potentially orphaned) commits that I had a hand in creating from today. Because some shit went down, and I need to view all of the commits that have failed to get labeled with branch pointers, because I may or may not have rebased stuff wrong.

Meanwhile the only way to do it that I came up with is with a manual workflow something like this:

```
git reflog --date=relative | head -n 36 | cut -d' ' -f 1 | uniq | tr '\n' ' '
```

This produces a one line space separated set of commit hashes which should contain all the commits I touched today, and I found out through trial and error that if I just pass this over to my fancy `git log --graph` alias that it will helpfully inject them in the graph where they belong, and I can regain some sanity that way.

As with any reasonably recyclable git related capability that I discover, I like to try to generalize in a script or at least some StackOverflow breadcrumbs so I can better learn how to do it quickly the next time that this happens.

A handy alias that lets me run my typical `git log --graph <lots of config>` but with the addition of also viewing all orphaned commits inside that graph would be amazing. But I definitely want to limit that to only show me such commits from the last one day.

Comment: I don't think you can do very much better than `git reflog --date=relative` or similar. The constant you have in your `head` (36) will depend on the number of reflog entries that fall into your desired time range, though. Processing the output in awk (looking for `seconds ago`, `minutes ago`, `hours ago`) seems like it might be easier, and then you could `print $1` to print just the hash, and even do the uniq-ifying in awk.

Comment: I was hoping that since `git reflog` is supposed to take log-options that it would "just work" but the use of log options seems to change its filtering. `--all` didn't work either.

I suppose I may settle for just dumping out the last 50 items and living with that.

Comment: The problem is that `git reflog` is (in this case anyway) just a wrapper for `git log -g` aka `git log --walk-reflogs`, and that runs `git log` in a way that makes it not walk commit history. You need to run `git log` twice: once with these reflog commits selected so as to find them, and then a second time, in the normal history-walking way.

Comment: Ah, yeah makes sense. I'd use the `--date=iso` on it then, at least that will be moderately safer to parse, though still not wonderful.

Comment: That should work better soon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664200/6309

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm that, after re-compiling Git after [commit 3ab01ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ab01ac3f7681a294a09b42b9b014dc48a9aee22) that I mention in "[How to properly use `git reflog --since=…`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664200/6309)", reflog does work as expected:

```
git reflog --since="2 days ago" --all
```

It is part of the [upcoming 2.14.2 release](https://github.com/git/git/commit/edc74bc7f0c6884027e851ef09b2e0c9380dcd45#diff-2bb611b014aab7186b29809271ec0e02R20), which should be out very soon.